# how to set value timer countdown from database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, timer

I'm try to put value of database in my timer for while power down I can get value of last timer so my program can run timer from last value not start from the beginning again.

```
var hj= document.getElementById("jam");
var mm= document.getElementById("menit");
var ds= document.getElementById("detik");


var startDateTime = new Date();
var cookie_time = getCookie("timer_start");
var startStamp = cookie_time?cookie_time:startDateTime.getTime();
setCookie("timer_start", startStamp, 1);
var newDate = new Date();
var newStamp = newDate.getTime();
var timer;
```

[This my code](http://jsfiddle.net/rjoxocyf/)

Comment: Do you mean cookie instead of database ? Because that's what your attempt is showing.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your expected result, i have used setinterval and without date

```
        //Pass database values to s,m,h and the timer will start from there          
              var s=35;
              var m=20;
              var h=10;
              document.getElementById('hr').innerHTML= h;
              document.getElementById('min').innerHTML= m;
              document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML=s;
              function pad(val) {
                    return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val;
                }

              var seconds=    setInterval(function(){ 
                      document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML= pad(++s);
                if(s==60){
                      document.getElementById('min').innerHTML=pad(++m);
               s=0; 
                  if(m==60){
                      document.getElementById('hr').innerHTML=pad(++h);
               m=0;   
                }
                }
              }, 1000);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="hr">00</div>:
<div id="min">00</div>:
<div id="sec">00</div>
```

Codepen- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/RRRvjg
hope this works for you :)

Comment: I have updated this codepen with same variables mentioned in this post -http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/XKKOEW but used same logic :)

Comment: @turtle, is this solution working for you with database values? :)